I am trying to match beginning and end of string of words
I have a string like

There was a school xyz**Relationships And Career:**however the job

I want to match **Relationships And Career**
I have tried ^\**.+:\**$
This is working when the search string is a new line all by itself, but not working when it is contained in the bigger string

There was a school xyz**Relationships And Career:**however the job


I want to match starStarRelationshipsAndCareerStarStar

Star is a special character in regexes.  You need to escape it.  \*.+:\*.  And you don't want '^' and '$' since it's in the middle of a line.

I wanted only the first match so I used *.+:?*  with the question mark
